# Using exclusions in parameters in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, parameters, coffeescript

I want to "refresh" parts of a website. I want to make a function where all of the parts will be refreshed except for those passed in the parameters. I am using a splat for the parameter, but I am stuck after that. Here is the code so far:

```
refresh = (exceptions...) ->
    $("#playersTotalHealth").text("Health: #{player.totalHealth}")
    $("#playersHealth").text("Your Health: #{player.currentHealth}/#{player.totalHealth}")
    $("#opponentsHealth").text("Enemy's Health: #{e1.currentHealth}/#{e1.Health}")
    ...
```

If I only wanted to refresh `#playersTotalHealth` then how can I use `exceptions...` to do that?

Comment: What sort of things would be in `exceptions`?

Comment: @muistooshort I can either do the id of each element or a variable containing the element. Whichever is easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more like a problem with the execution logic itself... You can just check if an item is present in the `exceptions` array:

```
# Not in the exceptions array, execute...
if "#playersTotalHealth" not in exceptions then $("#playersTotalHealth").text "Health: #{player.totalHealth}"
```

Comment: `if '#playersTotalHealth' in exceptions` would be more idiomatic in CoffeeScript.

Comment: Good hint. Updated my answer. Thanks!